# Sync chrome bookmarks

Tags: android, google-chrome, bookmarks

I've got a shiny new personal laptop and want to sync my mobile chrome bookmarks. I get how to do this in theory but am paranoid that the thing is going to be toocleverbyhalf and simply overwrite my mobile bookmarks with the bookmarks which I saved on my unsynced chrome installed on my work pc (which is nevertheless linked to my Google account). I can't find any way to export the mobile bookmarks on Android chrome as insurance including investigating the supposed multiplicity of apps which are supposed to do this. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'chrome://bookmarks/'. In options on top right, you will see option to Import and Export bookmarks. Export your saved bookmarks to a HTML file and import it wherever you need and sync to your google account.